# Pfsense 2.02 unstable ipsec vpn.Tunnels will come up upon restarting raccon

Tags: vpn, firewall, ipsec, pfsense

Pfsense 2.02 Ispec VPN tunnels drops randomly,but when the raccon service is restarted all tunnels are back up.Here is my ipsec vpn configuration.Any fix on this issue?
I have tried enabling and disabling "Prefer older IPsec SAs" and also tried disbaling and enbaling DPD but still no luck.I have to restart raccon daily to keep the tunnels alive.Is this a BUG?

Phase 1

- Authentication method : Mutual PSK
- Negotiation mode : Aggressive
- Policy Generation :Default
- Proposal Checking : Obey
- Encryption algorithm : 3DES
- Hash algorithm : SHA1
- DH key group : 5
- Life time :28800
- NAT T    : Disabled
- DPD  : enabled(60 secs and 5 retries)

Phase 2

- Protocol :ESP
- Encryption algorithms: 3DES
- Hash algorithms: SHA1
- PFS key group : 2
- Life time : 1800

racoon: [---------]: INFO: initiate new phase 1 negotiation: x.x.x.x[500]<=>x.x.x.x1500]

racoon: [---------]: INFO: IPsec-SA request for x.x.x.x1 queued due to no phase1 found.

racoon: ERROR: failed to begin ipsec sa negotication.

racoon: ERROR: phase1 negotiation failed due to send error.b52634c42b55942e:0000000000000000

racoon: INFO: begin Aggressive mode.

Answer (score 0):

That's likely the same cause as I described here: 
[Pfsense 2.02 ipsec vpn tunnel goes down randomly](https://serverfault.com/questions/495982/pfsense-2-02-ipsec-vpn-tunnel-goes-down-randomly/496336#496336)

misconfigured "Server IP" on PPTP server.